# Upload file to parent's folder (Carrierwave + s3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have a model "Image" with an uploader attached to it. Image belongs to multiple models. I'm using s3 to host my files.

Right now my path is: "image/file.jpg"

Once an image is uploaded I want the path to be "parent-model/image/file.jpg". How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

**file_uploader.rb**

```
   def store_dir
      "#{model.class.to_s.underscore}"
   end
```

**image.rb**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true

    mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

Comment: What result do you get right now?

Comment: Right now my path is: "image/file.jpg" @MichalSzyndel

Comment: Yes, that's because this is what you ask Carrierwave to do! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload file to proper dir you need to change the `store_dir` method to

```
def store_dir
  "#{model.imageable.class.to_s.underscore"/images/"
end
```

or maybe even

```
"#{model.imageable_type.underscore"/images/"
```

(you need to try this second one out, should work if association was persisted before.)